# Ошибка при запуске Gulp

Tags: gulp, npm, node.js

Уже пол дня мучаюсь, все запускается в отдельности кроме BrowserSync.

```js
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    sass    = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),
    concat    = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify   = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),
    cssnano   = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    rename    = require('gulp-rename'),
    del    = require('del'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    csslint   = require('gulp-csslint'),
    shorthand   = require('gulp-shorthand');;

gulp.task('sass', function(){
 return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.+(scss|sass)')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
  .pipe(csslint())
  .pipe(shorthand())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
 return gulp.src([
  'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
  ])
 .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

gulp.task('css-libs', ['sass'], function(){
 return gulp.src('app/css/libs.css')
  .pipe(cssnano())
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '_min'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
 browserSync({
  server: {
   baseDir: 'app'
  },
  notify: false  
 });
});

gulp.task('clean', function(){
 return del.sync('dist');
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'], function(){
 gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.+(scss|sass)', ['sass']);
 gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'sass', 'scripts'], function(){
 var buildCss = gulp.src('app/css/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

 var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));

 var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

 var buildHtml = gulp.src('app/*.html')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

 var buildPhp = gulp.src('app/*.php')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
 var buildImg = gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});
```

[image: Терминал с ошибкой]

Comment: где код запуска сервера? Там должно быть создание истнанса `browserSync`. В нем нужно параметр `open` установить в `false`. enSO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005867/

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!